# Only last plot in loop showing in figure

Tags: matplotlib

I'm tearing my hair out as I did this exact same thing last week successfully.

Basically, I have a class RBM, and this is what I do

```py
epochs = 10
#... (init rbms) 
for rbm in [rbm_200, rbm_500]:
    recon_loss = rbm.cd(whatever)
    x = list(range(epochs)) 
    plt.plot(x, recon_loss, label=rbm.__str__())
plt.savefig()
```

Only rbm_500 line will be there in the saved fig, and when I remove it from the list rbm_200 line is there. ARGH. I've tried giving them a unique colour, calling legend in the loop, initialising with plt.figure() etc etc etc.

Comment: do you want to save two individual figures, or do you want one figure with two subplots?

Comment: Maybe something inside `rbm.cd(whatever)` erases the plot? For example a call to `plt.figure()`?